# Remove the white border of Custom Dialog which is an activity

Tags: android-layout, android-manifest

I have a custom dialog, which has a label , a text box  and 2 buttons.
So i decided to build up a Activity which will look like a dialog, and in then Manifest file, i mentioned the theme as Dialog.

So now I get a custom dialog working fine.
But, i want to remove the white boder of this custom Dialog.

I read the other posts,which say we can remove the border using

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_white</item>
```

however in my case it is an activity, which looks like a dialog.
Please help

Comment: plz give your detail code

Answer (score 0):

Please apply below code instead of your one

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```